# QuerySet for non-empty TextField

Tags: django, django-models

For a model like:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ....
```

I'm attempting to do a simple queryset for all Items where the "notes" field is non-empty. Not finding mention of this capability in the docs, but via a comment on a bug report, discovered that you can actually compare with greater than:

```
items_with_notes = Item.objects.filter(notes__gt='')
```

This works, but feels like a hack. "Greater than" seems like it should be used for numeric comparisons, not for checking whether a text field is blank. Surprised not to find something like:

```
Item.objects.exclude(notes=blank)
```

Am I overlooking something, or is .filter(notes__gt='') the right way to do it?

Comment: In some cases it's also worth considering filtering by text length, for instance if it's likely your textfield consists only of whitespace characters or html elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314168/django-filter-on-the-basis-of-text-length

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`.exclude(notes=u'')`

Read more here: [django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude)

Comment: Ah, much better, thanks. I notice this works either with or without the "u" before the quotes. So what does the "u" accomplish?

Comment: The `u` in front of the string makes it a `unicode` literal. It doesn't accomplish much here, since the empty `str` decodes to the empty `unicode` trivially. It does save a tiny bit of time, but not enough to really worry about. I use unicode literals there always because Django uses unicode internally, and if something non-ASCII comes up then you don't want Django choking on it because you scrimped on a single keystroke.

Comment: You might also want to do `.exclude(notes=u'').exclude(notes=None)`

Comment: Are you sure that `.exlude(notes=None)` really works? I thought that that kind of checks should be done with `__isnull=True/False`:  
  
  
`.exclude(notes=u'').exclude(notes__isnull=True)`

Answer (score 3):

you can also use Q object:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Item.objects.filter(~Q(notes=''))
```