# django filter on the basis of text length

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to filter my model on the basis of the length of the text
Something like

```
MyModel.objects.filter(len(text) > 10)
```

where text is a Char or Text field in MyModel model

Comment: Use the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length function.

Answer (score -20, accepted):

It would be much better **and** faster if you just add a column that pre-calculates(memoizes) the length
of the text.

e.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    text_len = models.PositiveIntegerField()

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.text_len = len(self.text)
         return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

MyModel.objects.filter(text_len__gt = 10)     # Here text_len is pre-calculated by us on `save`
```

Comment: Is it because text field isn't indexed and the text length is calculated each time the query hit the database. The solution suggested by lain is doing the same, isn't it (although that solution isn't working for me).

Comment: @ashish 1) Yes it's pre-calculated. 2) No lain doesn't do the same.

Comment: 1) So if the length is pre-calculated, then why i need to have another column 2) lain's solution doesn't check for each expression if the character occurence is greater than n ??

Comment: @ashish I added a comment on the last line of the above code. We add a column to the model to store the length of the `text`. This is updated everytime the text is modified. So when we query the model, we can filter by the text length, which WE have pre-calculated on our `save` method.

Answer (score 299):

For modern Django (>=1.9) [@hynecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448474/hynekcer)'s [answer is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260608/623735).

For Django >= 1.8 you can use an *annotation* and the [Length function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(text_len=Length('text_field_name')).filter(
    text_len__gt=10)
```

Under the hood, Django uses is @Pratyush's suggested [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296333/623735) MariaDB (MySQL) function. But the Django `Length` function will work for any Django-compatible db by using `LENGTH()` for Postgres and other databases.

Comment: Say I don't want to filter the queryset, but instead return itself in with the objects `text_len__gt=10` in first place (`order_by`). Any hint?

Comment: @dabad, you can use the `text_len` *annotation* in the same way you would use any other database *field*, so it works in `order_by` or `Sum` or whatever.  To sort the results in decreasing text length order and return the length values: `MyModel.objects.annotate(text_len=Length('text_field_name')).order_by('-text_len').values_list('text_len', flat=True)`.

Comment: @guettli A problem with the accepted answer is, that the original poster has been seen last time in September 2015 at SO and your admirable altruism was the only possibility :-) I had to edit this answer before I could upvote. I added a similar [answer for Django >= 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260608/448474) that doesn't require annotate, but a global registration of `Length` Transform.

Comment: This is very difficult to find in the docs, because it's not grouped with other aggregations like `Sum`. It's also extremely important for many cases. I had a case where I needed to pre-check the maximum data size that a query might return won't run the server out of memory, and a variant of this worked perfectly.

Comment: @AlanSE the reason they didn't document it with Sum and other aggregations is because it's not an *aggregation*. It works on individual records (rows). The resulting queryset has the same number of rows as before running the `Length` operator. So it's called a *transformation* or a *mapping*. Aggregations *reduce* the number of records. *Mappings* do not.

Answer (score 67):

**Another way is:**

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["CHAR_LENGTH(text) > 300"])
```

This can be used where the text lenght is more than 255 characters too.

Comment: in case you have sqlite, it's `LENGTH(..)`.

Answer (score 66):

A nice solution for Django >= 1.9 is possible by registering the builtin function `Length` as a **Transform** for `CharField` lookup.

**Register** the transformation in the project once. (The best place is probably models.py.)

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Length

CharField.register_lookup(Length, 'length')
```

**Use**:

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(text__length__gt=10)
```

See exactly the same example in docs for [Length as a transform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#length).

---

It works correctly for all backends, compiled by `LENGTH()` for most backends and by `CHAR_LENGTH()` for MySQL. It is then registered for all subclasses of CharField automatically, e.g. for EmailField. The `TextField` must be registered individually. It is safe to register the name "length", because a transform name could never shade or be shaded by an equally named field name or related field name.

The only disadvantage could be readability puzzle: Where did the "length" come from? (The lookup is global, but the same can be luckily safely registered repeatedly in more modules, if useful for readability, without any possible overhead at query runtime.)

Other similarly valuable solution is the [hobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640020/448474)'s above that is shorter if a registration counts and if a similar query is not used repeatedly.

Comment: @guettli Unexpected that you had written a solution first and a minute before you started the bounty? I did it also in a strange order: I found details for the solution from Django source, then found it all is in the docs about finally that you had known the solution first.

Comment: I started a bounty since the accepted question, which still is unfortunately still the one on the top, was outdated. I was hoping that the answer with the Length function (>= Django 1.8) was getting more upvotes. AFAIK this happened, but unfortunately the outdated answer is still on the top.

Answer (score 34):

You can use the regex filter to search for text of a particular length:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(text__regex = r'.{10}.*')
```

---

Caveat: for MySQL, the maximum length value is 255. Otherwise an exception is thrown:

```
DatabaseError: (1139, "Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp")
```

Comment: As [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) says: `Using raw strings (e.g., r'foo' instead of 'foo') for passing in the regular expression syntax is recommended.`

Comment: I am getting this exception after executing the code              
**OperationalError: (1139, "Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp")**                             
and this is because of curly braces.

Comment: Actually the exception stated above is basically mysql exception.

Comment: This works fine for any number below 256. MySQL has a maximum repetition count of 256.

Comment: @emil-stenstrom actually, it's 255

Comment: You _might_ be able to step around the 255 repetition limit if your length is a multiple of items less than 255 - e.g. `r'(.....){205}'` for >1025 (I can't test this on a MySQL DB right now though)

Comment: Very clever. I wonder if this might be faster than using `LENGTH`.

Comment: This is truly the best answer, if you don't mind a slight performance decrease.

Answer (score -9):

I would solve the problem on your app server and not tax your database.  You can do this by:

```
models_less_than_ten = []
mymodel = MyModel.objects.all()
for m in mymodel:
    if len(m.text) > 10:
          models_less_than_ten.append(m)
```

Comment: This won't scale well for many rows in MyModel.  If you had 100,000 rows, it would be less taxing on the db to do a strlen & decide not to send a row, than sending tons of data to the app server to filter out.  It's almost always better to do the work on the db, and if it's too slow or taxing, the query can be optimized.