# Django: Lookup by length of text field

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model with a text field on it. I want to do a lookup that will return all the items that have a string with a length of 7 or more in that field. Possible?

How about a lookup for all objects in which that field isn't `''`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think regex lookup can help you:

```
ModelWithTextField.objects.filter(text_field__iregex=r'^.{7,}$')
```

or you can always perform raw SQL queries on Django model:

```
ModelWithTextField.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM model_with_text_field WHERE LEN_FUNC_NAME(text_field) > 7')
```

where len_func_name is the name of "string length" function for your DBMS. For example in mysql it's named "length".

Comment: Nice approach with the regex!

Comment: I wonder, is the SQL for length-checking available through the Django ORM?

Comment: I suppose no. Found this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314168/django-filter-on-the-basis-of-text-length), and there another good decision to store length in separate column, it's better way for performance.

Comment: Wonderful solution

Answer (score 13):

Since django 1.8, you can use the [`Length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length) database function:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
qs = ModelWithTextField.objects \
        .annotate(text_len=Length('text_field_name')) \
        .filter(text_len__gte=7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Django 1.9 the `Length` database function may be registered as a queryset lookup:

```py
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Length
CharField.register_lookup(Length, 'length')
```

So that then you are able use it in a following manner:

```py
# Get authors whose name is longer than 7 characters
authors = Author.objects.filter(name__length__gt=7)
```

See: [Database Functions - Length()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#length) in official Django 3.2 Docs