# Django - Filter queryset by CharField value length

Tags: python, django, django-south, data-migration

Given that I have a legacy model with a `CharField` or `CharField`-based model field like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, ...)
    ...
```

I need to make migrations to make it have a `max_length` of max. 255. First I'm writing a `datamigration` to make any values with longer than 255 characters adapt the upcoming `schemamigration` to fix the maximum length of the column, which I will do right after this works.

The issue is that I have a **very very large set of data** and I know not all the rows contain a value longer than 255 chars for `MyModel.name` and I would like to consider for my migration only those who do.

Is there any way (with) the django ORM to filter only the objects that meet this condition? Something like:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(name__len__gte=255)
```

would be great, but I believe this is not possible, or at least it's not this straightforward.

Does somebody know any way to accomplish this query?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [django filter on the basis of text length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314168/django-filter-on-the-basis-of-text-length)

Answer (score 28):

'Recent' Django versions have the built in `django.db.models.functions.Length` lookup/transform, so you can do:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(length=Length('text')).filter(length__gt=254)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#length

Old answer:

I think you have to options:

Using 'extra' on the queryset:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["CHAR_LENGTH(text) > 254"])
```

Or abusing Regex lookups, I'm assuming this will be slower:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(text__regex = r'^.{254}.*')
```

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL and found that regex to be a life saver.

Comment: Update: with Django 1.7 [custom lookups and transforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-lookups/) are easy to implement. So you could implement a transform that does exactly `test__length__gt=254`, where `length` is your custom transform.

Comment: Caution: read the warnings here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra
before using extra

Answer (score 7):

If you find that you are using a lot of extra and regex, following @BBT's suggestions, I went ahead and implemented the transform as follows:

```
# utils.db

from django.db.models import Transform
from django.db.models import CharField

class CharacterLength(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'len'
    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return "LENGTH(%s)" % lhs, params

CharField.register_lookup(CharacterLength)
```

Thereafter, I could do a cascaded lookup on "mycolname" as follows:

```
from utils.db import *

queryset.filter(mycolname__len__gte=10)
```