# How to apply a function on the values selected in Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Say I'm having the below model in Django

```
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    volumes = JSONField()
```

I want to get the length of title of all the Books as values -

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "volumes": [
            {
                "order": 1
            },
            {
                "order": 2
            }
        ],
        "length_of_volumes": 2
    },
]
```

I tried the following, but it's not the proper way to do it as it's not a CharField -

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
Books.objects.all().values('id', 'title', length_of_valumes=Length('volumes'))
```

Comment: Is this a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yes, It's a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 2):

`len('title')` will just determine the length of the *string* `'title'` which thus has five characters, so as `.values(…)`, you use `.values(length_of_title=5)`.

You can make use of the [**`Length`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

Books.objects.values('id', 'title', length_of_title=Length('title'))
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Book` instead of <s>`Books`</s>.

Comment: Actually I want the length of a jsonfield where I have an array. I had tried this earlier but it doesn't seem to work on jsonfiled.

Comment: @deltaforce then you should update the question for what you want so you don't get answers that don't work for you.

Comment: @deltaforce: in your question `title` is a `CharField`, and furthermore in your sample output it is also a string. It is not entirely clear to me *what* you want. Writing a JSON blob to  `CharField` will of course store the json blob as text, but that does not mean that Django or the database will *interpret* this as JSON, it is just text that "looks like" JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Willem's answer, but uses annotation.  Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640020/14757226.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
qs = Books.objects.annotate(length_of_title=Length('title')).values('id', 'title', 'length_of_title')
```

An advantage would be you can then add `filter` or `exclude` clauses to query on the length of the title.  So if you only wanted results where the title was less than 10 characters or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` structure:

```
values = []
for b in Books.objects.all().values('id', 'title'):
    values.append({
            'id': b.id, 
            'title': b.title, 
            'length_of_title': len(b.title) 
    })
```