# How to use the length method in Django ORM Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In the below class, I need to display the length of name above 25 and country =UK

```
class Emp(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
   country=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

I tried this ,but not working

```
from django.db.models import CharField 
from django.db.models.functions import Length
CharField. register_lookup(Length, 'length') 
result = Emp.objects.filter(country='UK','name__length__gte=10)
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640020/14354604

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django filter on the basis of text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314168/django-filter-on-the-basis-of-text-length)

Comment: I tried this ,but not  working                                                                     
from django.db.models import CharField                                                                   
from django.db.models.functions import LengthCharField.         
register_lookup(Length, 'length')                                                                    
result = MyModel.objects.filter(country='UK','name__length__gt=10)

Comment: If you copy-pasted that snippet as is, then it really won't work because there's a space between `ChartField.` and `register_lookup`. Also there shouldn't be an apostrophe `'` before `name__length__gte`. What do you mean by it's not working, is it just not returning the results you expected? Are there no error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length


result = Emp.objects.annotate(name_length=Length("name")).filter(country='UK', name_length__gte=25)
```

see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#length)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps, here is code snippet

```
 from django.db.models.functions import  Length
    from django.db.models import F
    result = YOUR_MODEL.objects.annotate(column_length=Length(F('Your_column'))).filter(column_length__lt=100)
    rating=result.all()
```